# To draw highligted line with finger over line in android

Tags: android, canvas, touch

I am developing an android app where I have two points(x1,y1) and (x2,y2) with already drawn line between them. Now I want to draw a line over it that highlights that line. Line is drawn using canvas.drawLine().

One more point if I draw highlighter line over the already drawn line...Do I have to restrict the user to draw line only over that existing line using onTouchEvent or their exist a method that will do the same for me

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, and with the lack of response, I think others may feel the same.

Comment: suppose you have one line and now user touches that line with his finger it restricts the user to highlight that very portion of line not the entire screen like in U Connect app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitlogik.uconnectlite&hl=en

I want same as the app's first screenshot where golden line only highlights the gray line not the entire screen.

Comment: You could achieve the same effect by drawing with two separate colors.  Untouched nodes and lines are drawn in grey, touched nodes and traced lines are drawn in gold.  You could even follow the users finger on the traced lines by checking how far down the line you are towards the next node, and drawing the line to that point in gold, and the line the rest of the way in grey.

Comment: Since we are using Android Canvas there is no way to identify that user is touching on the given lines of Graph not the other part of the screen.

Now if we could just store the node's x,y coordinate and identify that user is on the same line then the number of lines would be huge.

Is there a way to restrict the user to draw in certain portion not the entire screen?